# How to manage multiple transactions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I found a problem when processing multiple transaction using Entity Framework.

Please see the scenario below:

[Student table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STVG2.png)

Please note that the name field is required

`Student` entity:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; } 
}
```

Manage two transactions:

```
    var db = new TestContext();

    var student1 = new Student()
    {
        //Name = "John",
        Age = 30,
        score = 70
    };

    var student2 = new Student()
    {
        Name = "Peter",
        Age = 50,
        score = 75
    };

    using (var trans1 = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {

            db.Students.Add(student1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            trans1.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            trans1.Rollback();
        }
    }

    using (var trans2 = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {

            db.Students.Add(student2);
            db.SaveChanges();
            trans2.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            trans2.Rollback();
        }
    }

db.Dispose();
```

Please note that the first transaction was intentionally made to fail on because student1 missing name field, whereas student2 is fine.

However, when this piece of code got executed, neither student1 or student2 is created. It appears that if the first transaction fail and rollback, the second transaction fail too. Why?

I expect the second transaction will succeed because it can run successfully if I remove the first transaction block and just run the second transaction independently.

I can not find any similar cases, therefore open a new thread. Many thanks for clarifying my confusion.

============================================

It seems like transaction does not make any sense in this case. The following code remove the explicit transactions but the result is exactly the same.

```
var db = new TestContext();

var student1 = new Student()
{
    //Name = "John",
    Age = 30,
    score = 70
};

var student2 = new Student()
{
    Name = "Peter",
    Age = 50,
    score = 75
};

try
{

    db.Students.Add(student1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

try
{

    db.Students.Add(student2);
    db.SaveChanges();
    trans2.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

db.Dispose();
```

Please let me know why I can not get the expected result - the first SaveChanges() fail and the second SaveChanges() succeed. Thanks!

Comment: How to let the first SaveChanges() fail but the second SaveChanges() succeed?